# finding out the right intercepts of slope

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the given question, it has been said that, a>b so it can be negative. Therefore I assumed,  all the answers are wrong. But it is given that C and E are  right.  **How it can be?**

Comment: Try to consider some points mentioned : $$\text{Slope of line m is between 0 and 1.} $$ 

What is the formula for slope of two perpendicular lines?

Comment: It seems to say that $a\gt b\gt 0$, so I do not know what you say can be negative. The question can be settled by drawing a couple of pictures.

Comment: For two perpendicular line,  $slope_1 \times /slope_2 =-1$.How E is true? if E is true then we can not have the ratio of the y and x intercepts of line m  positive.

Comment: Regarding the title question: slopes do not have intercepts. Graphs of lines can have both slopes and intercepts, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following figure describes the condition given in the question.

[image: Two perpendicular lines m and n intersecting]

When you will consider the option a), the figure shall look like : [image]

Notice here that x intercept of line m is positive. (if you will extend it, it will cut the x axis at approx. positive x axis.)

Now, consider option b)
 [image: Option b)]

As you might have noticed here, that the slope of line m is still between 0 and 1. Rotate the line m, this shall give you something like this : [image: Rotate]

As your main problem lies for option $E)$ , thus, I'm going to consider that only.

Now, in the above figure (where line m is rotated) , you may notice that y intercept is positive and x intercept is negative. So, basically the condition goes like this : $$\text{When y-intercept} \ \text{is positive, then x - intercept is negative} \\
\text{When y -intercept is negative, then x-intercept is positive.} $$

So, the product of x-intercepts and y-intercepts will always remain negative. [the product can be zero as well.]